# Editing Schema file in BigCommerce Cornerstone Theme

Tags: schema, bigcommerce, microdata, product-variations, google-merchant-center

Google Merchant does not recognize my product size variations. The micro data that Cornerstone theme is generating is not display the different sku and price. I tried using Schema App but they can not edit theme files.
I am struggling with where to edit the schema.json files. I believe I know what to add but can not find how to edit the files.
This is the code I believe needed:

```
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org/",
  "@type": "Product",
  "name": "Clarks Falalala Shoes for Men",
  "image": "https://example.net/shoes/clarks-falalala.jpeg",
  "description": "A great comfortable walking shoe, carried in sizes 9-11, but now size 11 isn’t in stock",
  "offers": [ {
    "@type": "Offer",
    "sku": "QWERTYSHOE-9",
    "price": 45.99,
    "priceCurrency": "EUR",
    "availability": "InStock"
  },{
    "@type": "Offer",
    "sku": "QWERTYSHOE-10",
    "price": 45.99,
    "priceCurrency": "EUR",
    "availability": "InStock"
  },{
    "@type": "Offer",
    "sku": "QWERTYSHOE-11",
    "price": 45.99,
    "priceCurrency": "EUR",
    "availability": "OutOfStock"
  } ]
}
```

Please help me with where to edit schema file.
Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Your mixing a few terms here. schema.json I believe is an internal BigCommerce theme file to define properties of a theme. Like colours and features. It is not related to schema.org or structured data. Your example is schema.org based using the json-ld format (not microdata which is another format). 

Could you share where you got the example from. At the moment I'm not sure how the merchant centre wants us to mark up variant based products, or what works. Your example looks good if the merchant centre supports it.

Comment: I've spoken with google merchant support and they have told me that the schema/structured data needs to updated with the product variants. I got the code example from Schema App https://www.schemaapp.com/newsletter/schema-org-variable-products-productmodels-offers/, their support told me the microdata is what is not changing according to product. BigCommerce support also told me the microdata is controlled by the theme.
equiliteherbals.com/ani-motion is an example.
Please let me know if you need any other information @TonyMcCreath.

Comment: With BigCommerce this has always been an awkward area. With mixed limitations and rules with all involved. It sounds like schemaapp are saying they can't help. They can rewrite existing schema from a theme, but they typically do this in JavaScript. The merchant centre is unclear if they properly support JavaScript so schemaapp may not be an option. Those are questions you could pose to both parties. Also, the merchant centre documents how to markup variants differently. It would be good to get clarification from them if they support the schemaapp structure (and the use of javascript)